# Adding and validating 201 response on Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, http, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am using Swagger in Spring to create APIs according to OpenAPI standards.

I am trying to create an API with 201 SUCCESS response (Not the default 200). But Swagger includes 200 Response by default and my test case is failing.

```
@ApiResponses(value =
            {
                    @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found")
            }
    )
    @PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<...> createEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
        ...
    }
```

Failing test:

```
@Test
public void testCreate() throws Exception {
    String mockJsonData = <mock-json-input>
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("<url>")
            .content(mockJsonData)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

Test log:

```
Status expected:<201> but was:<200>
Expected :201
Actual   :200
```

I also changed Swagger Docket Bean

```
@Bean
 public Docket emplyeeApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                ...
```

It is acceptable to have 200 in Swagger, but I need to make my test case green, so that my API contract is future-proof.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Swagger does not include any responses by default. The code generation technology that you are using might. Is there a reason why you have not included the Swagger/OpenAPI specification that you are using?

Comment: Swagger does include default responses. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2312

Comment: That is a link to something called 'springfox'. Please post a link to the section in the official Swagger specification where default responses are described.